# Download file with resume capability using aiohttp and python

Tags: python-3.x, stream, aiohttp, download-manager, telethon

I want to stream and download file using `aiohttp`. 
Chrome can support the resume capability of download link
But the download manager cannot download the file with the resume capability.

In the code below I used aiohttp framework to stream and download the file, 
I've also set the header parameter ('Accept-Ranges') to support resume capability.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
client = TelegramClient(name, api_id,api_hash)

@routes.get('/{userid}/{msgid}')
async def handle(request):
    ...
    response = web.StreamResponse(
        status=200,
        reason='OK',
        headers={
            'Content-Type': content_type,
            'Content-Length':str(file_size),
            'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        }
    )
    await response.prepare(request)
    async for chunk in client.iter_download(msg.media, chunk_size=512):
        await response.write(chunk)
    return response

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes(routes)
web.run_app(app,host='0.0.0.0')
```

When the download link is hit in the browser,the file is well streamed.
Resume capability is well supported in Chrome,
I expect the download manager to be well supported resume capability, but after the pause hits and starts downloading again,download manager unable to continue downloading and requires user to restart download.
The message `IDM` gives: "When trying to resume the download, internet download manager got response from the server that it does not support resuming the download ..."

Comment: Seems like an issue with `IDM`, the `aiohttp` and `telethon` part look correct to me. You even claimed Chrome has no trouble with this.

Comment: Yes. I have no problem with Chrome.
Do I need to write extra code for `http` header
Or was it done in `teleton` ?

Comment: Oh also, you should use the `offset=` parameter in `iter_download` to "resume from a byte offset". But even then, it doesn't explain why IDM fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basing ourselves on this [streamer implementation](https://github.com/andrew-ld/webgram/blob/a76f9bb2fa5d15c901f337c0e545776903cadaa6/webgram/streamer.py#L17-L79), it seems like you are missing `Content-Range` and `status=206` to indicate [Partial Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/206).

Probably something like the following might work. Note that it doesn't do enough validation (i.e. the `Range` from the headers may be invalid).

```
import re

...

async def handle(request):
    offset = request.headers.get('Range', 0)
    if not isinstance(offset, int):
        offset = int(re.match(r'bytes=(\d+)', offset).group(1))

    size = message.file.size
    response = web.StreamResponse(
        headers={
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
            'Content-Range': f'bytes {offset}-{size}/{size}'
        },
        status=206 if offset else 200,
    )
    await response.prepare(request)

    async for part in client.iter_download(message.media, offset=offset):
        await response.write(part)

    return response
```

Comment: When I set up ‍‍‍‍`status=206 if offset else 200` it goes into Chrome easily `pause` and `start` but inside `IDM`  button `start` and `pause` not activated.
When I set `status=206` into Chrome it is failed ,but it activates on `IDM` `start` and `pause` but when I hit `pause` and `start` download, the following error occurs:`telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.LimitInvalidError: An invalid limit was provided. See https://core.telegram.org/api/files#downloading-files (caused by GetFileRequest)`

Comment: I test  `webgram` on my server, but it has problem with `IDM` too.Inside `IDM` buttons start and pause not activated, but inside chrome everything is good

Comment: `LimitInvalidError` should be handled correctly by `iter_download`, so this may be a bug in the library.

Comment: I found out that `aiohttp` has problem with  `IDM` and it is not relate to `telethon` package